# Woodstox parser works fine in test run in Eclipse, but fails from command line

Tags: maven-3, woodstox

One of my JUnit tests uses (behind the scenes) the Woodstox parser.

When I run the test from within Eclipse, the test succeeds as expected.

But running the same test on the command line, using

```
mvn clean test -Dtest=com.example.MyClassTest#someParserTest
```

results in the test to fail with the following exception messages:

```
Error on line 114 column 21
  SXXP0003: Error reported by XML parser: Invalid UTF-8 middle byte 0x3f (at char #4174, byte #3999)
    ...
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.reportInvalidOther(UTF8Reader.java:314)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.UTF8Reader.read(UTF8Reader.java:205)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.ReaderSource.readInto(ReaderSource.java:84)
    at com.ctc.wstx.io.BranchingReaderSource.readInto(BranchingReaderSource.java:55)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.StreamScanner.loadMore(StreamScanner.java:961)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.readTextSecondary(BasicStreamReader.java:4580)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.finishToken(BasicStreamReader.java:3657)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sr.BasicStreamReader.next(BasicStreamReader.java:1063)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sax.WstxSAXParser.fireEvents(WstxSAXParser.java:524)
    at com.ctc.wstx.sax.WstxSAXParser.parse(WstxSAXParser.java:452)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.sendSAXSource(Sender.java:440)
    at net.sf.saxon.event.Sender.send(Sender.java:171)
    at net.sf.saxon.jaxp.IdentityTransformer.transform(IdentityTransformer.java:363)
```

I took a look at the to-be-parsed `InputStream`. The `InputStream`s are identical in both cases.

Also, there is no "line 114 column 21" in the `InputStream`. Line 114 ends on column 11.

How can I investigate what causes the different behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that a library I used made wrong assumptions about the environment's default character encoding (also called *platform's default charset*).

In the Eclipse environment, calling `Charset.defaultCharset()` returned *UTF-8*, while in the command line environment it returned *CP1252*.

Many standard and third-party Java APIs behave differently depending on the platform's default charset, among them:

- `String.getBytes()`
- `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString()`
- `XMLOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter(OutputStream stream)`
- `IOUtils.toString(InputStream input)`

To resolve my issue, I had to update that library to explicitly use the correct character set:

- `String.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`
- `ByteArrayOutputStream.toString( StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() )`
- `XMLOutputFactory.createXMLStreamWriter( OutputStream stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() )`
- `IOUtils.toString(InputStream input, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)`